# .NET with OpenLDAP

Tags: .net, openldap

I'm trying to get my application to authenticate users stored on OpenLDAP. There are no APIs for .NET as far as I can find and there're only libraries available for Java.

I have tried DirectoryEntry with DirectorySearcher with no success and LDAPConnection did not work either.

Has anyone worked on anything similar?

Comment: It'll help if you specify a language tag, so more people can see your question and hopefully provide appropriate answers.

Comment: I thought .net was enough. I am aiming to get more specific answers rather than people pasting what they find on Google... :)

Comment: True, but I had to add the .NET tag :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this for VB .Net:

```
' for networkcredential
Imports System.Net
Imports System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryConnection
Imports System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection
Imports System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier

Public Function IsAuthenticated( ByVal username As String, ByVal pwd As String) As Boolean
          ' against OpenLDAP

        Dim strLDAPServer As String = String.Empty

        'users full DistinguishedName in OpenLDAP
        Dim uid As String = "UID=" & username & _
         ",ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"

        strLDAPServer = "my.openldapserver.com"

        Dim ldapDirectoryIdentifier As New System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier(strLDAPServer, 389, True, False)
        Dim networkCredential As New NetworkCredential(uid, pwd)
        Try
            Dim ldap As New System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection(ldapDirectoryIdentifier, networkCredential)
            ldap.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = False
            ldap.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
            ldap.AuthType = ldap.AuthType.Basic
            ldap.Bind()

        Catch lex As Exception
            'Authentication fails - bad username or password

            Return False
        End Try



        Return True

    End Function
```

based on C# .Net post here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2012/05/07/sample-code-to-query-openldap-directory-via-net-system-directoryservices-protocols.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Search for a user
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
                                          "LDAP://127.0.0.1/ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com",
                                          "cn=Manager, dc=maxcrc, dc=com ",
                                          "secret",
                                          AuthenticationTypes.FastBind
                                         );
object obj = entry.NativeObject;

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
searcher.Filter = "(cn=agent001)";
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
if (result != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
```

Comment: You may want to provide some more information when answering a question.

Comment: where is the "authenticate" bit ? :)